# How to remove "Expired license" message in VMWare Player?

Tags: vmware-player, license

I'm using VMWare Player to run some virtual machines. Recently I needed to use the VMWare Virtual Disk Manager utility (to convert some dynamic disks to fixed), and since it doesn't come with Player, I installed the evaluation version of VMWare Workstation. After I was done, I uninstalled Workstation and reinstalled Player, but apparently Player thinks I'm still using an evaluation licence because it shows "Expired license" in the title bar and the following message in the main window:

> Your evaluation license has expired. To continue commercial use of this product, purchase a license.

[image]

How can I revert back to the free-for-personal-use version of VMWare Player? I've already tried completely uninstalling all VMWare products and reinstalling Player, but that doesn't work, the "Expired license" message persists.

Comment: Did you buy it??

Comment: Buy what, VMWare Player? No.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue myself, but check [VMware Player Expired License](http://patrickhoban.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/0759/) and [VMware Player 5: license expired...](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/420857?start=0&tstart=0) for possible solutions. Basically you should delete the license registry key which was left behind. The actual key name might be slightly different depending on the VMware version.

Comment: @and31415 That worked, thanks! Please post it as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Indrek Could you specify which version of VMware Player and VMWare Workstation were you using? Also, what was the name of the registry key you had to delete and where was it located, exactly? I'd like to include that information, too.

Comment: @and31415 I'm using VMWare Player 6.0.1. Workstation was version 10. The registry key I deleted was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VMware, Inc.\VMware Workstation\License.ws.10.0.e1.201303.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

After uninstalling the VMware Workstation trial, the old license key might be left behind. Deleting the related registry key will revert VMware Player back to the original, free-for-personal-use state.

The actual registry key name depends on the product name and version. For example, VMware Workstation version `10.0.1` uses a key called `License.ws.10.0.e1.201303`. The format appears to be the following:

```
License.<product>.<major>.<minor>.<revision>.<date>
```

The registry location will be different depending on whether Windows is [32-bit or 64-bit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827218/en-us). Respectively:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware Workstation
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VMware, Inc.\VMware Workstation
```

1. Close VMware Player.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Navigate to the correct path described above.
4. Locate the license registry key, right-click it and choose **Delete** from the context menu.

### References

- [VMware Player Expired License](http://patrickhoban.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/0759/)
- [VMware Player 5: license expired...](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/420857)

Comment: Didn't work.. :(